# C# Extract Resource from Native PE

Tags: c#, resources, portable-executable

I seem to be failing to find the correct answer to what I am trying to do here.

In my C# code, I would like to extract resources from *another* executable that would be passed by user prompt. The other executable would be a native PE file.

As an example, I need to pull the `KDATA\106` resource from this PE file (`sample.exe`). This is what it looks like in ResourceHacker.

[image: ResourceHacker display of PE resources]

I seem to be only able to find info on how to extract from *my* program, or parsing from another project.

Comment: `string exeContents = File.ReadAllText(exeFilePath, Encoding.GetEncoding(28591));` - thats how you get the bytes, is that all you need? or do need help showing the bytes as Hex? or is it organising the bytes like ResourceHacker does? If you want everything you'll have to show us your code, what you have so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: @JeremyThompson In the example above, I need the bytes of the resource itself (2E373235). I have no issue converting bytes to strings, etc., but I need a way of parsing the PE file and extracting the resource itself. I'm currently trying to marshal FindResource and other functions from kernel32.dll, I'll add a snippet once I think I get some progress.

Comment: You should put it as an answer, people will read all that and get to the end to find out its solved.

Comment: Yep, was planning to flesh it out more as an answer when I get some time soon. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up marshalling the code and handling this as if it was C++.

One important thing to note about `FindResource()` is that it expects the `lpName` to be prepended with `#` if you pass it a string instead of an integer. [MSDN Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648042(v=vs.85).aspx)

> If the first character of the string is a pound sign (#), the remaining characters represent a decimal number that specifies the integer identifier of the resource's name or type. For example, the string "#258" represents the integer identifier 258.

First I marshal out all of the important functions from kernel32.dll in a separate class, then call the resource by name and type. (I grabbed most of this class from a blog that I cannot find again, will link if I locate it again.) Note that I have marshaled the parameters of `FindResource` as *strings* and not integers, for simplicity in C# (no need for hacks with `MAKEINTRESOURCE`).

**ResourceManager.cs**

```
class ResourceManager
{    
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryEx(string lpFileName, IntPtr hFile, uint dwFlags);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindResource(IntPtr hModule, string lpName, string lpType);
    //  public static extern IntPtr FindResource(IntPtr hModule, int lpName, uint lpType);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadResource(IntPtr hModule, IntPtr hResInfo);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr LockResource(IntPtr hResData);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern uint SizeofResource(IntPtr hModule, IntPtr hResInfo);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool EnumResourceNames(IntPtr hModule, string lpType, IntPtr lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);

    public static byte[] GetResourceFromExecutable(string lpFileName, string lpName, string lpType)
    {
        IntPtr hModule = LoadLibrary(lpFileName);
        if (hModule != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            IntPtr hResource = FindResource(hModule, lpName, lpType);
            if (hResource != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                uint resSize = SizeofResource(hModule, hResource);
                IntPtr resData = LoadResource(hModule, hResource);
                if (resData != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    byte[] uiBytes = new byte[resSize];
                    IntPtr ipMemorySource = LockResource(resData);
                    Marshal.Copy(ipMemorySource, uiBytes, 0, (int)resSize);
                    return uiBytes;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Main.cs**

```
public Main(){

    string path = @"C:\sample.exe";
    // Get the raw bytes of the resource
    byte[] resource = ResourceManager.GetResourceFromExecutable(path, "#106", "KDATA");

}
```

Comment: I would change it to `LoadLibraryEx(lpFileName, IntPtr.Zero, LoadLibraryFlags.LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);` in order to support 32\64 bit files. Signature: `[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)] static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryEx(string lpFileName, IntPtr hReservedNull, LoadLibraryFlags dwFlags);` (The flags can be taken from here: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/LoadLibraryFlags.html?diff=y)